# Facebook Save Button: Post failed (404)

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

Has anyone the same Problem?

I got the example from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/save?locale=en_US

After pressing the "Save-Button" i got the success message from facebook but nothing was added. Console displays the following error.

**The Error:**

```
POST: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/save/sentry/?dpr=1
```

**Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your Website Title</title>
  <meta property="og:url"           content="https://www.instagram.com/facebook/" />
  <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />

  <style>
  .fb-save, span, iframe {
    width: 200px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-save" data-uri="https://www.instagram.com/facebook/" data-size="large"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No idear? :( The problem is still there..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay i found the problem! I missed the App-Id....

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=12345679";
```

or

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'your-app-id',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.5'
  });
};
```